# tox can't find python version

Tags: python, pip, tox

I have a `tox.ini` that needs to install a package in editable mode. However, the package has no `setup.py` - meaning that in order to install it, a new `pip` version (I think 21.4 is enough, but just to be sure, I enforce >=22)

To run this locally, I just run:

1. `python3 -m virtualenv venv`
2. `. venv/bin/activate && pip install pip>=22`
3. `. venv/bin/activate && pip install -e <pkg-path>`

My `tox.ini` looks like:

```
[tox]
envlist = py3
requires =
    tox-pipenv >= 1.10
; Older pip can't install in editable mode without setup.py
    pip >= 22.0.0

[testenv]
; Install "pkg" in editable mode
deps =
    -e <pkg-path>
commands =
    ...
```

This throws the following:

```
int(version_dict["major"]) if version_dict.get("major") is not None else major
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.tox/bin/python'

================================================================================ log end ================================================================================
ERROR: InvocationError for command .../.tox/.tox/bin/python -m pipenv --python .tox/bin/python (exited with code 1)
________________________________________________________________________________ summary ________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   py3: InvocationError for command .../.tox/.tox/bin/python -m pipenv --python .tox/bin/python (exited with code 1)
```

which means, that for some reason, I don't have a valid python...

I suspect the

```
    tox-pipenv >= 1.10
    pip >= 22.0.0
```

lines, but I can't make it right

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround - but it works.

I found out (after checking several versions manually) that `virtualenv==20.10` comes with a new enough `pip`, so I tried using that...

I replaced the

```
    tox-pipenv >= 1.10
    pip >= 22.0.0
```

with another dependency - `virtualenv`:

```
requires =
; Older pip can't install in editable mode without setup.py. I couldn't enforce
; pip version directly, but enforcing virtualenv is good enough, becuase it has
; it's own pip inside, and this version has a new enough pip version
    virtualenv >= 20.10
```

and for some reason - this works!

---

There is a weird issue here: the following line (which I used to see whenever I built the old `tox.ini`) is missing:

> .tox installdeps: ...

Not sure what it means, but I think that probably something is wrong on my setup. It is possible that this works only because my default `virtualenv` is now updated...

**EDIT: False alarm :) It is actually the correct solution... The reason I didn't see that line was because `tox` skipped it because it already has satisfied the requirements. Now I downgraded `virtualenv` and the line is back :)**